# validation before unwind ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue

Is there a way to do a validation before unwind a ViewController?

i have my ViewController1 and there is a unwind function

```
    @IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

       // make stuff with data
}
```

And a button from ViewController2 is conected with that unwind function, and i pass data from my ViewController2 to ViewController1 in `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`
all works fine, but i want to do some validations.

```
if sender as? UIBarButtonItem == self.saveButton  {

        if let content = self.textFieldContent.text {
            publish.content = content
            publish.image = self.image
        } else { 
           self.alertMessage("Content is empty")
        }

    }
```

The `self.alertMessage()` function appears but the ViewController2 is dismissed every time. And i dont want this to happens, how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use - (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender method instead if you need prevent unwinding on some conditions.